# React Native: Issue with TextInput Focus - Keyboard Not Opening on Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue in my React Native project related to the TextInput component on Android. When I tap on the input field, the keyboard does not open. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onFocus={() => handleFocus()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function handleFocus() {
  console.log('Input field focused!');
  // Additional logic if needed
}
```

I've confirmed that the onFocus event is triggered, and I see the log message in the console. However, the keyboard doesn't appear on the Android emulator.

I've reviewed the React Native documentation and searched for similar issues, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested your code on my Android emulator, everything seems to be working fine. onFocus event gets triggered and keyboard pops up. You should try with different emulator or try wiping the current one.